# Symfony: It's possible load different parameters.yml?

Tags: symfony, parameters, multi-tenant, saas

It's possible to load different parameters.yml on symfony? I have a SaaS multitenant APP and I wish load differents parameters.yml (with config DB) base on each tenant in order to dispatch the user to the correct DB on login action.

Thanks so much!

**EDIT: SOLVED!**

I solved it arranging the different tenants configurations in folders like:

```
app
---config
------tenantA
---------config.yml
---------config_dev.yml
---------config_prod.yml
---------parameters.yml
------tenantB
---------config.yml
---------config_dev.yml
---------config_prod.yml
---------parameters.yml
------tenantC
---------config.yml
---------config_dev.yml
---------config_prod.yml
---------parameters.yml
....
```

And, modifying the loader of kernelApp.php:

$loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/**TENANT**/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');

I don't know if this is a good practice but it works fine!

Comment: If you want use doctrine Migrations, you'll run into a problem, because it is independent of this config.

I have a solution, if you want go to doctrine migrations, you can read it here, and i say thanks to you, because you pointed me to the right direction of using multiple databases and same source ;-)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45633339/symfony3-doctrine-migration-with-multiple-databases

Comment: I think `kernelApp.php` approach you described above will cache your config. for example: if `tenantA` config is loaded it will be cached and loaded for `tenantB` as well.. (acknowledging post being 3 years old!)

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilities here.

If tenant's number is a constant or close to it (new tenants are added very rarely) you can simply setup several connections as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html). After that you can get necessary `EntityManager` instance by calling

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager($dynamicValue);
```

Downside of this approach is that you must modify your `config.yml` each time you need create/update/delete a tenant.

But if you want more flexible approach you can implement your own class for managing database connections:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Entity\Database;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;

/**
 * Class ConnectionManager
 * @package AppBundle\Service
 */
class ConnectionManager
{
    /**
     * @var Connection[]
     */
    protected $connections = [];

   /**
     * @param Database $database
     * @return Connection
     * @throws DBALException
     */
    public function getConnection(Database $database)
    {
        $params = [
            'dbname' => $database->getName(),
            'user' => $database->getUser(),
            'password' => $database->getPassword(),
            'host' => $database->getHost(),
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        ];

        $key = $this->getKey($params);
        if (isset($this->connections[$key])) {
            return $this->connections[$key];
        }

        $conn = DriverManager::getConnection($params);
        $this->connections[$key] = $conn;
        return $conn;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $params
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getKey($params)
    {
        sort($params);
        return md5(implode('.', $params));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrey. I'm looking for dispacht de "login" order on symfony to the correct DB. I have many databases (one for each tenant) but when a user log on symfony, the order atacks the DB deffined on parameters.yml. Just i'm looking for load the correct paratemers.yml by the domain before a user log in symfony. (Sorry about my english :/ )

Comment: @CarlosCarmona - Sounds like you want a different parameter.yml based on the request?  Not going to happen.  All the config stuff is done once and then cached.  It will always be the same for each request.  You will need to do something like this answer suggests.

Comment: @Andrey I solved it arranging the differents tenants configurations in differents folders in (app/config/tenantX), loading by appKernel de corret environment by domain. It works fine!! :)

Comment: @CarlosCarmona congratulations!